# How to override a NewCommand in DetailsCollectionViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

Have this code in ViewModel:

```
public CollectionViewModel<EfAttach, Guid, IDomainModelContextUnitOfWork> EfIncomingAttachesDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return GetDetailsCollectionViewModel((EfIncomingViewModel x) => x.EfIncomingAttachesDetails, x => x.Attaches, x => x.DocumentId, (x, key) => x.DocumentId = key);
        }
    }
```

This is Detail for ViewModel

And XAML code

```
<Grid dxb:MergingProperties.AllowMerging="False" x:Name="EfIncomingAttachesDetailsPanel" dxb:BarNameScope.IsScopeOwner="True" DataContext="{Binding EfIncomingAttachesDetails}" dxlc:LayoutControl.TabHeader="{x:Static res:Resources.Attaches}">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <dxb:ToolBarControl>
                                    <dxb:BarButtonItem BarItemDisplayMode="ContentAndGlyph" Content="{x:Static res:Resources.New}" Command="{Binding NewCommand}"  Glyph="{dx:DXImageOffice2013 Image=New_16x16.png}"/>
                                    <dxb:BarButtonItem BarItemDisplayMode="ContentAndGlyph" Content="{x:Static res:Resources.Refresh}" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"  Glyph="{dx:DXImageOffice2013 Image=Refresh_16x16.png}"/>
                                </dxb:ToolBarControl>...
```

How to override a command on button "New"?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not quite clear to me. Please, specify what things exactly you want to change (command's caption? command's image? command behavior? or just replace the entire command with another one?)

Comment: I'm sorry, my thought was very chaotic. Let me explain. There ViewModel for example IncomingViewModel
By IncomingViewModel tied IncomingView containing a ICollection fields and text fields generated from IncomingModel. I want to perform commando (eg NewCommand) and then send a Message.
For me it is clear IncomingViewModel simply override NewCommand and command will be executed for the context IncomingViewModel.
And what to do with commando to create a new row in the table for the slave? How do I change it or intercept?  [link](http://imgur.com/ycFUYXB)

Comment: Thank you, now your question is absolutely clear to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `GetDetailsCollectionViewModel` method implementation - this implementation is trivial. Based on this implementation, you can create your own method which returns a specific DetailsViewModel as follows:

```
public IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel EfIncomingAttachesDetails {
    get { return GetIncomingAttachesDetails(x => x.EfIncomingAttachesDetails); }
}

protected IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel GetIncomingAttachesDetails(
    Expression<Func<EfIncomingViewModel , IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel>> propertyExpression) {
    return GetCollectionViewModelCore<IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel, EfAttach, EfAttach, Guid>(
        propertyExpression, () => IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel.Create(UnitOfWorkFactory,
                AppendForeignKeyPredicate<EfAttach, EfAttach, Guid>(x => x.DocumentID, null),
                CreateForeignKeyPropertyInitializer<EfAttach, Guid>((x, key) => x.DocumentID = key, () => PrimaryKey),
                () => CanCreateNewEntity()));
}
```

Here the `IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel` is implemented as follows:

```
public class IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel : CollectionViewModel<EfAttach, Guid, IDomainModelContextUnitOfWork> {
    internal static IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel Create(IUnitOfWorkFactory<IDomainModelContextUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory = null,
        Func<IRepositoryQuery<EfAttach>, IQueryable<EfAttach>> projection = null,
        Action<EfAttach> propertyInitializer = null,
        Func<bool> canCreateNewEntity = null) {
        return ViewModelSource.Create(() => new IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel(unitOfWorkFactory, projection, propertyInitializer, canCreateNewEntity));
    }
    protected IncomingAttachesCollectionViewModel(IUnitOfWorkFactory<IDomainModelContextUnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory = null,
        Func<IRepositoryQuery<EfAttach>, IQueryable<EfAttach>> projection = null,
        Action<EfAttach> propertyInitializer = null,
        Func<bool> canCreateNewEntity = null)
        : base(unitOfWorkFactory ?? UnitOfWorkSource.GetUnitOfWorkFactory(), x => x.Attaches, projection, propertyInitializer, canCreateNewEntity) {
    }
    public override void New() {
        base.New();
        /*  do something here */
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW! That's cool! And what I need ! It is logical and very easy! Thank you !!